# postfix: unable to Telnet into port 25 on centos 6.7

Tags: linux, postfix

## Introduction

1. New digitalocean droplet with Centos 6.7 i686 
   (centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.i686)
2. Nginx 1.1.13 (built from source code):

   - installation: https://gist.github.com/c80609a/cfa06e9ed11afd730145ba4cc14795db
   - `$ nginx -V`: https://gist.github.com/c80609a/333708fe1a826981f85b1c06daab2932
3. Cyrus:

   ```
   $ sudo yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-imapd
   $ sudo vi vi /etc/cyrus.conf: 
    -> https://gist.github.com/c80609a/7190c4981365447063ce2e06a517d9fd
   $ sudo vi /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf:
    -> pwcheck_method: auxprop
    -> auxprop_plugin: sasldb
    -> mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 
    ...
   $ sudo chkconfig --level 345 cyrus-imapd on
   $ sudo service cyrus-imapd start
   $ sudo service cyrus-imapd status
    -> cyrus-imapd (pid  1851) is running...
   ```
4. POSTFIX (postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.i686)

   ```
   $ sudo yum install postfix
   $ sudo vi /etc/postfix/master.cf
   -> https://gist.github.com/c80609a/07b397d2baa7455896bb704aa2a7479a 
   $ sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
   -> https://gist.github.com/c80609a/831168401df84b395c393b09a3cda384 
   $ sudo vi /etc/postfix/virtual: webmaster@site.org webmaster\@site.org
   $ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual 
   $ sudo touch /etc/postfix/body_checks 
   $ sudo service postfix stop
   $ sudo service postfix reload
   $ sudo postfix upgrade-configuration
   $ sudo service postfix start
   $ sudo service postfix status
   master (pid  16811) is running...
   $ sudo postfix status
   postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 16811
   ```
5. Two records added (digitalocean.com -> login -> networking):

   ```
   A mail 95.85.24.200
   MX 5 mail.site.org.
   ```
6. Mail sent successfully:

   ```
   $ echo 'test' | mail -s 'test' my@mail.ru
   ```

## Problems

1. Telnet connection refused:

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 25
   Trying ::1...
   telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   ```

   Try the google host - OK:

   ```
   $ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
   Trying 74.125.136.26...
   Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 mx.google.com ESMTP t6si2618629wjt.255 - gsmtp
   quit
   221 2.0.0 closing connection t6si2618629wjt.255 - gsmtp
   Connection closed by foreign host.
   ```
2. Unexpected netstat output (**the last column is undefined**):

   ```
   $ netstat -ln |grep :25
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
   ```

   Expected result:

   ```
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      16811/master
   ```

How do I fix these problems?

Comment: But you do get a connection on port 25 according to your post? Just not on your IPv6 interface. The last output also tells you it's bound on port 25 for IPv4 addresses. Are your sure your server is configured to respond to IPv6 requests and has a valid public IPv6 address?

Comment: @Seth, thank for question! I have enabled IPv6 interface for my droplet, it've helped to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection refused you get is only on IPv6, on the IPv4 address (127.0.0.1) you do get a connection. If you want to enable IPv6, you need to add the following line in `main.cf`:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
```

Regarding the netstat output, you need to use the `-p` switch to show process names, compare:

```
mtak@dc2:~$ netstat -ln | grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25       0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::25            :::*                 LISTEN
```

and

```
mtak@dc2:~$ sudo netstat -pln | grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      3102/master
```

Comment: I have just added `inet_protocols` mentioned above and enabled ipv6 for the droplet and reboot the server. I get a connection and type commands (like `quit`) but don't see any reaction and answer output (ctrl+x, ctrl+q not working, ~90 sec hold and bash returns).

Comment: The problem was solved. In total my mistakes are: instead of `telnet localhost 25` I need to use 'telnet mail.site.com 25' (according posfix `main.cf` parameter `myhostname`); to show process names in netstat output I need to use the `-p`.